# Program doesn't print out expected value

Tags: java, object

I tried to run a simple program that:

- initializes a variable

  `int a = 0;`
- reassigns it

  `a = 1;`
- prints it

  `System.out.println(a)`

---

Here is my code:

```
public class Main {

    int a = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Main main = new Main();
        main.go();

    }

    public void go() {

        a = 1;

        Main obj = new Main();

        System.out.println(obj.a);
    }

}
```

---

- `System.out.println(obj.a)` prints out 0;
- Why doesn't it print out 1?

Comment: `a = 1;` is equivalent to `this.a = 1;`.

Comment: You have two different objects.  They don't affect eachother.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `go` method creates a new instance of `Main` and prints the value of `a` of that new instance, which is 0. `a` is assigned `1` only in your original `Main` instance.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are creating a new object or instance of class `Main` in your `go` method.